# PHP: can't send arabic characters to twitter

Tags: php, twitter

i use this to update status on twitter
http://tutorialswalk.info/demo/twitter-update-php-oauth/

you can download it from the tutorial link

but when i type in arabic "مرحباً" it not update the status, what is the problem?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to encode it to UTF8?
I am sending hebrew characters with no problem.
http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php